# Bring form2 to front from a deactivated form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form1 that opens form2 as a "fake popup"

```
this.enabled = false;
MyForm2 myform2 = new MyForm2();
myform2.Show();
myform2.BringToFront();
```

When i dispose form2 i enable form1 back.

Now if the user minimizes both forms, and then clicks on form1, form1 will pop in his disenabled state.
I need to pop form2 insted.

So I created a static class to hold my last active form. On load of form2(or any other form) i save my last active form.

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnLoad(e);
   MyStaticClass.lastForm = this;
}
```

In form1(and other similar forms) i use:

```
    protected override void OnGotFocus(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        if (!this.Enabled && MyStaticClass.lastForm!= null && MyStaticClass.lastForm != this)
        {
           MyStaticClass.lastForm.Show();
            MyStaticClass.lastForm.BringToFront();
            MyStaticClass.lastForm.Activate();
        }
    }
```

OnGotFocus gets executed and my show/activate etc does too, but form2 never pops up. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
gg

Comment: How about using a Modal popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "showing" and "activating" your form, the problem is it's still minimized. Change the WindowState to Normal.

```
MyStaticClass.lastForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: This worked, but only when i discarded OnGotFocus for onActivate. Not sure why. Oh and the code: MyStaticClass.lastForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

Comment: @ggpuz - Yea, I'm at work so I was going off memory. I'll fix it so others don't fumble through it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be confusing to the user to click on one window's taskbar button and get another.

Instead of going through this rigamarole, try calling ShowDialog() instead of Show() in form1; this will block all access to Form1 until Form2 closes. ShowDialog also has an overload that accepts a "parent" or "owner" form; if this overload is used (just pass `this`), the dialog will always show in front of Form1.